# How to convert jp2000 to geotiff using GDAL?

Tags: macos, raster, gdal, data-conversion, geotiff

I'm trying to convert [Sentinel-2 imagery](https://remotepixel.ca/projects/satellitesearch.html) in jp2000 (.jp2) format to geotiff format using gdal_translate. However, it appears `.jp2` format is not recognized. What method should I use to convert jp2000 format to geotiff?

```
$ gdal_translate B02.jp2 B02.tif
ERROR 4: `B02.jp2' not recognised as a supported file format.

GDALOpen failed - 4
`B02.jp2' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

Comment: Do you have the JP2 driver installed? You can find out with gdalinfo --formats | grep JP2

Comment: Looks like the JP2 driver is not installed.

Comment: What OS are you using, and what version of gdal (gdalinfo --version)? For linux installing gdal through conda will come with the JP2 driver

Comment: @lpdudley I'm running Mac osX and I do not have anaconda installed.

Comment: @lpdudley I used conda install GDAL but didn't find the JP2 driver. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on macOS and want JP2000 with GDAL, one option is to use **homebrew** to install it like this:

```
brew install gdal --with-complete
```

Then you get this:

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep -i jp

  JPEG (rwv): JPEG JFIF
  JPEG2000 (rwv): JPEG-2000 part 1 (ISO/IEC 15444-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the jasper jp2 driver in gdal cannot handle big jp2 files. Also, there is no easy way of changing the jp2 driver of gdal.

So, simply install Kakadu from:
http://kakadusoftware.com/downloads/

Then convert your large jp2000 file to geotiff using Kakadu:
kdu_expand -i input.JP2 -o output.tif -num_threads 4

Then you can use your gdal functions with the converted geotiff.

Comment: This utility turned the JP2000 into a monochrome TIFF much larger than that produced by gdal_translate which I happen to have  some driver that successfully converts. I was looking for survival of the georeferencing.